# Respond to a Growl Notification using Applescript

Tags: applescript, growl, growlnotify

I Have a script which updates the working copy of my SVN and puts up a growl notification. What i want to do is, IF i click on the notification then a specific finder location must get open in a new finder window. Is this thing is possible using only Apple Script?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear so. That would require Growl running an arbitrary Applescript under specific circumstances, and [their documentation](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php) doesn't show that ability. As I see it, the only reasonable alternative would be to add in your initial script the ability to open the folder.